# Pyhaproxy job gives Not specify host and port in `frontend` definition

Tags: python, haproxy

I'm having a small problem with my pyhaproxy script, and I'm hoping that you can lead me in the correct direction.

My haproxy.cfg contains two frontends...

```
frontend http
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    acl test_site1 hdr(host) -i test_site1.local
    use_backend test_site1_back if test_site1
    etc. etc.

frontend https
    bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private
    option forwardfor
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    acl test_site1 hdr(host) -i test_site1.local
    use_backend test_site1_back if test_site1
    etc. etc.
```

The haproxy works just fine - no problem there.

Part of my pyhaproxy clean up script looks like this:

```
haproxy_cfg = '/etc/haproxy.cfg'
haproxy_bak = '/etc/haproxy.bak'

parser = Parser(haproxy_cfg)
configuration = parser.build_configuration()
frontends = configuration.frontends
backends = configuration.backends
```

It gives the following error message: [line 287 is configuration = parser.build_configuration()]

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./cleaner.py", line 287, in 
>    configuration = parser.build_configuration()
>
> File "/a-lot-of-folders/python2.7/site-packages/pyhaproxy/parse.py", line 41, in build_configuration
>
> self.build_frontend(section_node))
>
> File "/a-lot-of-folders/python2.7/site-packages/pyhaproxy/parse.py", line 203, in build_frontend
>
> 'Not specify host and port in `frontend` definition')
>
> Exception: Not specify host and port in `frontend` definition
>
> Segmentation fault

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Regards - Lars

Comment: My haproxy is version 1.7.5-2 2017/05/17